# how to avoid duplication by setting document Id in the case that an elasticsearch index is input and a mysql database is output?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, elastic-stack

In my case scenario I am using an elasticearch index as input :

```
input{
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://***.***.***.***:9200"
    index => "****"
    user => "***"
    password => "***"
    query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
    ssl => true
    ca_file => "/etc/logstash/newfile.crt.pem"
    codec => "json"
  }
```

}

and mysql database as output :

```
output {
if "PRV_API_REQUEST" in [message] {
jdbc {
  driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***/indexname? 
  user=test&password=****"
  enable_event_as_json_keyword => true
  statement => [
    "INSERT INTO indexname (logLevel, timestamp, requestURL, date, response_code) 
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    "logLevel",
    "timestamp",
    "requestURL",
    "date",
    "[response][code]"
  ]
  }
 }
}
```

my question is how to avoid duplication and to set it and what to add to my configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you inserting the elasticsearch's document_id in your table? Maybe you could add a condition to your SQL statement to verify if the document_id already exists, with something like that:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (document_id, field1, field2, ...)
VALUES (v_document_id, v_field1, v_field2, ...)
WHERE v_document_id NOT IN (SELECT document_id FROM TABLE)
```